# Porting eye texture UVs from SFM to Blender

Tags: texturing, uv, image

Not sure if this is the right place to ask, but for some reason when I port some models from SFM to Blender, the eye texture UV maps get messed up. I think it's because SFM has a different eye texture system than Blender. Is there an easy fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

That's just how some eye textures are set up in SFM. The best way to fix it is to take a picture of the model with the eyes set up in SFM and use it as a reference for editing the UVs in Blender.